# Compile-time types generation in constexpr functions

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, c++14, constexpr

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

typedef std::tuple<const int> TupleType;

constexpr std::array<const int, 2> a = {1, 2};

constexpr void foo()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        const int j = i;
        typedef std::tuple_element<j, TupleType> T;
    }
}
```

The code can not be compiled by ***gcc-7.2*** with ***--std=c++17*** with the following compilation error:

```
error: the value of 'j' is not usable in a constant expression
note: in template argument for type 'long unsigned int'
```

If we assume that function (and the corresponding loop) is evaluated in compile-time (which is viable for loops starting from **c++14**), why then this code can not be compiled as far as, even though **i** is not declared as **const**, it can actually be **constexpr** as all of its values are known at compile-time as well.

Could you please clarify whether this code is invalid by its very idea? Or there is a compiler limitation? Or none of the following?

Answer (score 2):

> Could you please clarify whether this code is invalid by its very idea?

It is - you are trying to use a mutable and stateful iteration variable as a *constant expression*. The whole concept of a *constant expression* revolves around immutability. It doesn't matter if the loop is executed during compilation.

What you actually should do here is **generate code** for the following snippet:

```
{
    typedef std::tuple_element<j, TupleType> T;
    // ...
}
```

Where `j` is a placeholder for a *constant expression*. Here's a possible way of doing it:

```
template <typename F, typename... Ts>
constexpr void for_each_arg(F&& f, Ts&&... xs)
{
    (f(std::forward<Ts>(xs)), ...);
}

constexpr void foo()
{
    for_each_arg([](auto c)
    {
        typedef std::tuple_element<c, TupleType> T;
    },
    std::integral_constant<int, 1>{}, 
    std::integral_constant<int, 2>{});
}
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KxezjfbWSe4Ovs1D)

Note that higher-level abstractions over `for_each_arg` could be easily provided *(e.g. iterate over a compile-time range of numbers, or convert a `constexpr` array to a sequence of `integral_constant` and iterate over that instead)*.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is right. `i` and `j`and not constexpr. Look for yourself:

```
//    v--- not constexpr
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Not constexpr either
        const int j = i;
        typedef std::tuple_element<j, TupleType> T;
    }
```

If you try to mark `j` constexpr, you'd see that since `i` is not, it cannot be so.

If you try to declare `i` constexpr, you will see that constexpr variables are subject to the same rule as any constexpr variable: you cannot mutate them.

So how can you loop over numbers to generate the types?

You can use pack expansion with index sequences:

```
template<typename T, T... S, typename F>
void for_sequence(std::integer_sequence<S...>, F f)
{
    using unpack = int[];
    (void) unpack{(f(std::integral_constant<T, S>{}), void(), 0)..., 0};
}

constexpr void foo()
{
    for_sequence(std::make_index_sequence<a.size()>{}, [](auto i)
    {
        typedef std::tuple_element<i, TupleType> T;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every `constexpr` function must be able to be evaluated at runtime.

`constexpr` does not mean "must run at compile time", it means "could possibly be run at compile time".

There is no fundamantal reason why you could not have a `constexpr for` loop that made the index a `constexpr` value on each iteration.  But C++ does not have that.

It does have a `constexpr if` which is similar in spirit to what you want.

Until it gets that, you have to write your own.

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
constexpr auto index_over( std::index_sequence<Is...> ){
  return [](auto&& f){
    return decltype(f)(f)( std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is >{}... );
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto index_upto( std::integral_constant<std::size_t,N> ={} ){
  return index_over( std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}
template<class F>
constexpr auto foreacher(F&&f){
  return [f](auto&&...args){
    ( (void)(f(decltype(args)(args)), ... );
  };
}

constexpr void foo()
{
  index_upto<a.size()>()(foreacher([](auto I){
    typedef std::tuple_element<I, TupleType> T;
  });
}
```

is an uncompiled exampke in C++17 (mostly 17 because it has constexpr lambdas).